# Basic Java example - Help needed

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Hi everyone I need help with this part of my java code

```
public void getMydata() {
    
    String B;
    databaseAds= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("AdmbAd");
    databaseAds.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            String myBannerID = snapshot.child("bannerId").getValue().toString();
            

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

        }
    });
}
```

the question is how can modify this code to be able affect the value of myBannerID that I get from the server ( in onDataChange Method)  to the String B located out of this method?

Comment: what about B = snapshot.child("bannerId").getValue().toString(); ?

Comment: Declare B as a private/public global variable in class

Answer (score 0):

Since the call you are making is asynchronous you could set a callback function in your getMyData method with the **java.lang.reflect.Method**

```
public void getMydata(Method method) {
    
    String B;
    databaseAds= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("AdmbAd");
    databaseAds.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            String myBannerID = snapshot.child("bannerId").getValue().toString();
            method(myBannedId);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

        }
    });
}
```

The way you invoke a **Method** Object is

```
Method callbackMethod = Main.class.getMethod("callback", parameterTypes[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You will not be able to modify a local variable from a callback

Whatever you're doing with your `B` string, you'll need to do it inside the `onDataChange` method

Beware, also, that `addValueEventListener` is an async process so if you write something like

```
public void getMydata() {
    
    System.out.println("1");
    databaseAds= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("AdmbAd");
    databaseAds.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            System.out.println("2");
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

        }
    });
    System.out.println("3");
}
```

it's quite likely to happen that the output is

```
1
3
2
```